# Change navigation title text by table index cell data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have implemented table view with paging enabled and cell size is device screen size , what i want to do is to change navigation bar title by index data of table cell when it completely scrolled

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let doseData = topDoseData[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationItem.title = doseData.value(forKey: "posted_on") as? String
}
```

Comment: You should provide us some code or at least a Screenshot of what you have and what you want to achieve. Your question is not clear for now

Comment: I tried to change navigation title in cellForRowAt indexPath method but it's not working properly, like i want to change navigation bar title when table cell end scrolling to next index and than next index data will be navigation bar title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing page title by getting visible cell

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in dosetable.visibleCells {
    let indexPath = dosetable.indexPath(for: cell)
    let doseData = doseArry[(indexPath?.row)!]
    let post_interests = doseData.value(forKey: "post_interests") as! [AnyObject]
    let bttnImgUrl = post_interests[0].value(forKey: "image") as? String
    let intrstTag = post_interests[0].value(forKey: "id") as! String
    let postIntrest = doseData.value(forKey: "post_interests") as! [AnyObject]
    bttnImg.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: bttnImgUrl!))
    intrestTitle.setTitle(postIntrest[0].value(forKey: "name") as? String, for: .normal)
    intrestTitle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(intrestBttn(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    intrestTitle.tag = Int(intrstTag)!
    intrestBttn.tag = Int(intrstTag)!
    intrestBttn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(intrestBttn(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    timeAgo.text = NSLocalizedString((doseData.value(forKey: "posted_on") as? String)!, comment: "")
    intrestBttn.setBackgroundImage(bttnImg.image, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything set as expected the problem might be in your data. You may unwrap the optional value to find where you missed at. You can try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let navigationController = self.navigationController else {
        fatalError("navigationController has not been set yet")
    }

    let doseData = topDoseData[indexPath.row]

    guard let title = doseData.value(forKey: "posted_on") as? String else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find data with key: posted_on")
    }
    navigationController.title = title
}
```

I put fatalError just for debugging purpose.

Comment: When page load first time index start from 1 and when i scrolled down than it start from 0